# Delphi, обучение. описание структуры

Tags: delphi, структуры

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться с описанием структуры программы и типом **record**. 
Дело в том, что я не знаю вообще как его применять на практике, что есть огромный минус. 
Помогите разобраться на примере:

*Описать следующую структуру:*
**Сотрудник**
**ФИО**
**Дата поступления**
*с вариантной частью записи:*
**Студент: Средний Балл**
**Сотрудник: Личный №**
**Другое: Комментарии**
*Написать процедуры ввода/вывода содержимого записи.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример

```
type
    TSomeone = Record
        Name : String[100]; // Общее имя
        Case IsStudent : Boolean of
            True  :
                (Score : Integer); // Балл только для студента
            False :
                (Id    : Integer); // Номер только для сотрудника
    end;
```

и

```
var
    Student, Employee : TSomeone;

begin
    Student.Name = 'John';
    Student.IsStudent = True;
    Student.Score = 9;

    Student.Name = 'Maxx';
    Student.IsStudent = False;
    Student.Id = 16;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Здесь](http://www.delphibasics.ru/Record.php) подробное описание структур, как с ними работать, как использовать вариантные структуры.

Comment: это прочитал, но все равно не имею представления, как это связать с элементами на форме программы.. можно примерчик хоть какой нибудь..

Comment: По ссылке есть вполне наглядный пример